# Python virtualbox api cannot add disk to SATA controller

Tags: python-2.7, virtualbox

I'm having a hard time to ass a disk to a SATA controller with virtualbox API when using a SAS controller everything works great but here I have a huge traceback that I do not understand. Do I have to do something special with the SATA controller? Thanks for helping

cheers,

```
import time
import os
import virtualbox
from virtualbox.library import StorageBus, IMachine
from virtualbox.library import IStorageController, LockType
from virtualbox.library import DeviceType, MediumVariant
from virtualbox.library import VBoxErrorObjectNotFound
from virtualbox.library import IStorageController, LockType, IVirtualBox
from virtualbox.library import IVirtualBox, AccessMode

session = virtualbox.Session()
sup = virtualbox.VirtualBox().find_machine("test_machine")
sup.lock_machine(session,LockType.write)
current_interface = IVirtualBox()
medium = current_interface.create_hard_disk("VDI", "/home/luffy/mine.vdi")
progress = medium.create_base_storage(1024*1024, [MediumVariant.fixed])
progress.wait_for_completion()
opened_medium = current_interface.open_medium("/home/luffy/mine.vdi", DeviceType.hard_disk, AccessMode.read_write,False)
session.machine.attach_device("SAS",2, 0, DeviceType.hard_disk,opened_medium) # This one works
session.machine.attach_device("SATA",2 ,0 ,DeviceType.hard_disk,opened_medium)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualbox/library.py", line 10264, in attach_device
    in_p=[name, controller_port, device, type_p, medium])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualbox/library_base.py", line 173, in _call
    return self._call_method(method, in_p=in_p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualbox/library_base.py", line 199, in _call_method
    raise errobj
virtualbox.library.OleErrorInvalidarg: 0x80070057 (The port and/or device parameter are out of range: port=2 (must be in range [0, 0]), device=0 (must be in range [0, 0]))
#session.machine.save_settings()
session.unlock_machine()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to set the max port count and then add the SATA hard disk

```
IStorageController sc = machine.getStorageControllerByName("SATA");
sc.setPortCount(sc.getMaxPortCount());
```